# How to run an action hook on Red Hat OpenShift?

Tags: openshift, travis-ci, chmod, pre-build-event, action-hook

I read the documentation about [Action Hook Scripts](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-action-hooks.html) for OpenShift and created a `pre_build` action hook with the following commands on my OpenShift gear:

```
rhc ssh jbosswildfly
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/.openshift/action_hooks
touch pre_build
chmod a+x pre_build
```

Afterwards I created the `pre_build` file in the Git repository of my OpenShift application and pushed it to the repo. My deployments to OpenShift are performed by Travis CI and I got the following response:

```
remote: NOTE: The .openshift/action_hooks/pre_build hook is not executable, to make it executable:
remote:       On Windows run:   git update-index --chmod=+x .openshift/action_hooks/pre_build
remote:       On Linux/OSX run: chmod +x .openshift/action_hooks/pre_build
```

So I executed `git update-index --chmod=+x .openshift/action_hooks/pre_build` (because I am running on Windows) and pushed that `pre_build` file again to my remote Git repository.

Now I get the following message:

```
remote: No such file or directory - /var/lib/openshift/54e8f8984382ecc9a1000047/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/action_hooks/pre_build
```

Why does it tell me now that it cannot find the `pre_build` file? If I login (via SSH) to my OpenShift gear, then it's there:

[image]

This is my `pre_build` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World
```

Comment: Make sure it's added to your git repo.  You can always winscp or ssh into your gear and check to make sure the file is there and the proper permissions are set after the git push.

Comment: The permissions for the `pre_build` file are set to `rwx`.

Comment: Hmm. Strange. Do a force stop and then restart.

Comment: Can you post the entire pre_build script?  It should have a shebang at the top of it for whatever language it's written in, such as #!/bin/bash

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I added the contents of my `pre_build` file. It starts with `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Can you ssh into your gear and give us the output of "ls -lah" in your repo/.openshift/action_hooks directory?

Comment: Sure! Here it is: http://snag.gy/mLXrJ.jpg

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer I am experiencing the exact same problem right now. Did you come to a certain solution? I'd be more than glad to know

Comment: @user1107412 - Unfortunately, I could not find a solution so far. We should consider [filing a bug for OpenShift Online](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi).